# Using ValueConversion in a XAML application in Windows 8.1

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, xaml, windows-phone-8

I'm in the process of creating a simple value converter for a temperature windows phone 8.1 application I'm creating for work. See, I found a great example here (http://www.nullskull.com/faq/74/using-convertback-method-in-an-ivalueconverter.aspx).

So, happy to found this example, I went on back to my wp8.1 application to continue my job. Thing is, MSDN says that it is not supported in 8.1 and also on a lot of platforms.

This brief introduction leads to the following question: Is there anyway to implement the IValueConverter interface in Windows 8.1 without having to use the generic methods :  Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language) & ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)

You'll be able to find below the code from the example I'm trying to use. Thank you for your insight !

```
[ValueConversion(typeof(double), typeof(double))]
public class FahrenheitToCelsiusConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("value");
        }
        // Fahrenheit to Celsius
        double fahrenheit;
        if (double.TryParse(value.ToString(), out fahrenheit))
        {
            var celsius = (fahrenheit - 32) * 5 / 9;
            return celsius;
        }

        throw new ArgumentException("value must be double");
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("value");
        }
        // Celsius to Fahrenheit
        double celsius;
        if (double.TryParse(value.ToString(), out celsius))
        {
            var fahrenheit = celsius * 9 / 5 + 32;
            return fahrenheit;
        }

        throw new ArgumentException("value must be double");
    }
```

Comment: Provide the source for `MSDN says that it is not supported in 8.1 and also on a lot of platforms`.

Comment: I tried the code, but when i tried to build the solution, there were errors in my converter class telling me that the interface was not  implemented and gave studs @dkozl

Comment: @kennyzx It seems that I read to fast. The correct thing on msdn was "Windows 8.1, Windows Server 2012 R2, Windows 8, Windows Server 2012, Windows 7, Windows Vista SP2, Windows Server 2008 (Server Core Role not supported), Windows Server 2008 R2 (Server Core Role supported with SP1 or later; Itanium not supported)"

Comment: What I just did on my computer was simply change cultureInfo instances in string instances. Since I'm not using neither, I thought it would have any impact on my code and it seems like yes. But this is peculiar. I think the example I took was not implementing correctly the interface which lead to my build errors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not implementing the interface correctly.

The signature of the two methods are

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, 
        object parameter, string language)

public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, 
        object parameter, string language)
```

Note the last parameter is string, not CultureInfo. The example you were after is for WPF. You can refer to [this sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.data.ivalueconverter), it is for WP.

Comment: Thanks that's exactly what I did ! You are correct indeed. I did not take the time to look at the definition of the interface which would have explained why it didn't work.